# (sqlite3.OperationalError) unknown database "seller"

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pytest, pydantic

I'm trying to use a testdb(sqlite) to make my tests, but when i use Base.metadata.createall() to create the same tables of the production database, i got this error: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unknown database "seller".

Conftest.py:

```
DATABASE_URL = 'sqlite:///testedb.sqlite'

@pytest.fixture(scope="function")
def client() -> Generator:
    config_database(DATABASE_URL)
    with TestClient(app) as c:
        yield c
```

Database.py:

```
Base = declarative_base()

def config_database(database_url):
    engine = create_engine(database_url)
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

Example of model there i'm using:

```
class Seller(Base):

__table__ = Table(
    "seller",
    Base.metadata,
    Column(
        "seller_id",
        Integer,
        primary_key=True,
        index=True,
        nullable=False),
    Column("cnpj", String, nullable=True),
    Column("nickname", String, nullable=False),
    schema="seller")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some database back-ends like PostgreSQL and MS SQL Server support the notion of a database containing multiple schemas, each of which can contain tables, views, stored procedures, etc.. If we are connected to a database named "my_db" then

```sql
SELECT * FROM seller.thing
```

means 'select rows from the table named "thing" in the schema named "seller" in the current database (my_db)'.

Other database back-ends like MySQL and SQLite do not support schemas within a database. Instead, they treat "schema" and "database" as synonyms, so

```sql
SELECT * FROM seller.thing
```

means 'select rows from the table named "thing" in the database named "seller", regardless of the current database'.

Therefore,

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, Table, MetaData

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///data.db")

thing = Table(
    "thing",
    MetaData(),
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
    schema="seller",
)
engine.echo = True
thing.create(engine)
```

will fail with the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unknown database seller
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE seller.thing (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

]
```

if the current SQLite database does not have an attached database named "seller".

That might be a bit confusing because in the above example the database "data.db" will be created automatically if it does not exist, but that happens when the code tries to establish a (DBAPI) *connection* to the database. The same "auto-create" behaviour does not occur when an SQL statement tries to *refer* to another database.

So, if you want to use a "schema" named "seller" in SQLite then you need to ATTACH it to the current database like so:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, event, Integer, Table, MetaData

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///data.db")

@event.listens_for(engine, "first_connect")
def schema_attach(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    dbapi_connection.execute("ATTACH DATABASE 'seller.db' AS seller")


thing = Table(
    "thing",
    MetaData(),
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False),
    schema="seller",
)

engine.echo = True
thing.create(engine)
```

(Note that in this case "seller.db" *will* be automatically created if it does not exist.)